# Efficient way of sorting a List<Point> by X value

Tags: java, sorting

I am doing some sort operation and the data structure that I am using is a `List<Point>`.

Now this Point has two values `x` and `y`, and the values are given not in a sorted manner.

I have to sort this `List<Point>` in an efficient way according to the value of x, either increasing x or decreasing x.

One solution can be a brute force approach of parsing through each value and comparing that value to all the other to find the smallest in each iteration but that will be an inefficient approach.

What other solution can be used for this problem.

Edit : Point is from [`org.opencv.core`](http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.2/org/opencv/core/package-summary.html) package.

Comment: why not to write a `Point class` and override the `equals()/hashcode()` and other operators then just apply sort. Or you can use `Map` class available.

Comment: @SatishPatel Have y value also attached to x.

Comment: So... are you asking about [sorting algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm)?

Comment: @Pelocho A direct sorting cannot be applied in this case.

Comment: Why? So you need sorting without possibility to sort?

Comment: @Pelocho I mean an inbuilt API for sorting cannot be used in this case.

Comment: But you have a data structure that contains all your points. And you'll be surely capable of accessing both x and y. And you want to sort the points. And there are several sorting algorithms. I don't get why you can't sort it

Comment: @Pelocho Because it is inside Point which is inside List. Brute force approach is there but something effiicient I need in this case.

Comment: You have a `List` of `Point`. Right. **Sort it**. Both `x` and `y` are public. Thre are **lots** of sorting algorithms and you're not telling any reason for not using them

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you are talking about class [`java.awt.Point`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html),
thus having a `getX()` method.

Using Java 8 you can sort points by `x`:

```
List<Point> points = ...;
points.sort(Comparator.comparing(Point::getX));
```

In lower versions of Java, such as 7, you can implement the `Comparator` to achieve this:

```
List<Point> points = ...;
Collections.sort(points, new Comparator<Point>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Point p1, Point p2) {
        return Double.compare(p1.getX(), p2.getX());
    }
});
```

Comment: That's good answer, and many people will be helped with this. But unfortunately in my case it is `org.opencv.Core`

Comment: @arqam, it shouldn't be an issue `points.sort(Comparator.comparing(point -> point.x));` use `lambda` expression instead of method reference.